# Change picture from already selected pictures in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, edit

Initially there will be set of images at left and right. if i click set image on left side. it will be moved to right side. right side column will show the selected pictures, left side column shows unselected pictures. i will be able to select 5 pictures at a time and submit it. if i click submit button those 5 images will be shown in another page,post request will be sent to server.there will be one button in that page called change picture button. if i click that , i need already selected images to be shown at another page of right hand side column.

Here is the plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/BM4AavLn9uKxKL4wdbT6?p=preview

```
 <body ng-controller="myController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;text-shadow: 0px 4px 6px;">All Pictures</h3>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="media in pinMedia">
      <!-- pin.media_id!=media._id || -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
        <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{images}}" width="200px" />
        <p>{{media.Name}}</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
          <button ng-disabled='limit()' class="btn btn-success" style="border: .0625rem solid transparent;padding: .465rem 1rem;" ng-click="toselected(media)">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
 Set Picture</button >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;text-shadow: 0px 4px 6px;">Selected Pictures</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="media in selected">
      <!-- pin.media_id==media._id && -->
      <div>
        <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{images}}" width="200px" />
        <p>{{media.Name}}</p>
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-success " style="border: .0625rem solid transparent;padding: .465rem 1rem;" ng-click="tosource(media)">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
 Remove Picture</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <button ng-click="setMediaForCurrentPin(selected)" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:50px auto; display:table;">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The expected behavior, the desired behavior, and the relevant code must be **in the question itself**.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated the description

Comment: @NitheshSD you have to write proper description to understand

Comment: @NitheshSD It's still not clear what the issue is.  After a quick inspection of your plunker it looks like you've got most of what you describe already.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think the issue is.he ll select the images in one page and he ll show those selected 5 images in other page.In showing page, he had one button called **change picture** ,he is sending put or post request to server after selecting 5 images in selecting image page.he ll set some images first and it will be shown in showing page. if he click change picture button it will redirect to selecting image page. in selecting image page, those images which are already selected to be shown at right side of the result in plunker. he need exactly showing the images which are already selected(posted or put)

Comment: For better understand please check this video http://nimb.ws/nYkCtx